# Uploaded dSYM files have unknown version

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, xcode-cloud

I want to upload dSYM files to the firebase crashlytics from Xcode cloud. I'm using ci_post_xcodebuild.sh script to automate that task. Here is what it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
if [[ -n $CI_ARCHIVE_PATH ]];
then
    echo "Archive path is available. Let's run dSYMs uploading script"
    # Move up to parent directory
    cd ..
    echo "Archive path: $CI_ARCHIVE_PATH"
    echo "Bundle ID: $CI_BUNDLE_ID"
    echo "Build number: $CI_BUILD_NUMBER"
    echo "Derived data path: $CI_DERIVED_DATA_PATH"

    # Crashlytics dSYMs scripts
    if [ $CI_BUNDLE_ID = "com.example.com" ]
    then
        echo "This is a production build."
        $CI_DERIVED_DATA_PATH/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp enovcanik-ios/App/Production/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios $CI_ARCHIVE_PATH/dSYMs/
    else
        echo "This is a staging build."
        $CI_DERIVED_DATA_PATH/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp enovcanik-ios/App/Staging/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios $CI_ARCHIVE_PATH/dSYMs/
    fi
else
    echo "Archive path isn't available. Unable to run dSYMs uploading script."
fi
```

Everything seems to be fine but when I open firebase crashlytics console version for uploaded dSYM is unknown. How do I fix that?

Tried to zip dSYM folder and uploaded it like that. Tried to set version manually but upload-symbols doesn't have option for that.

Comment: Are you sure `$CI_ARCHIVE_PATH` points to the right path of the correct archive build version? Every Archive you build creates another folder, therefore the path isn't the same always.

Comment: `$CI_ARCHIVE_PATH` is set by Xcode cloud and always has a value `/Volumes/workspace/build.xcarchive`. What do you mean by "Every Archive you build creates another folder"

Comment: You're right, my bad. [Apple's Documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/environment-variable-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `My_App_Name.app.dSYM` at the end of the dSYMs paths.

```bash
... -p ios $CI_ARCHIVE_PATH/dSYMs/My_App_Name.app.dSYM
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

... -p ios $CI_ARCHIVE_PATH/dSYMs/My_App_Name.app.dSYM
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```